# ClientY gives me Nan but pageY and offsetY is working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the mouse position and for that I use the following code:

```
function calculateMousePos(e) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        var root = document.documentElement;
        var mouseX = e.offsetX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
        var mouseY = e.offsetY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
        return {
            x: mouseX,
            y: mouseY
        };
    }
```

It works fine, but the tutorial I was using asked to use 'ClientX' and 'ClientY' instead of offsets and or pageX/Y etc.

But whenever I use ClientX/Y , the position I get is NaN, I checked it out by console logging the mouse positions.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was typo. I figured it out when looking at my code randomly for errors. I had been typing ClientX instead of clientX.